# Loop seems like it should break but wont

Tags: python-3.x

I cant stop it from going back to rosterInput even when 0 is entered. (its in the right format in the ide but I cant seem to make it right on here for some reason.) Also will this properly store multiple inputs from the user in a list that I can later print in a different function?

```
def add():
#adding team members...
global roster
roster = []
rosterInput = roster.append(input("New member or members: "))
while rosterInput != "0":
    add()
    if rosterInput == "0":
        mainMenu()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're saving the result of `roster.append` into `rosterInput`, not the result of `input`. Append returns `None`.

Instead, do

```
rosterInput = input("New member or members: ")
roster.append(rosterInput)
```

Edit: To correct the issue of never going to the main menu, move the if clause outside of the while clause, and you don't need the if anyway. Also, your `rosterInput` never changes during the `while`-loop, so I think you should read `rosterInput` again after `add()`. In summary, to do it iteratively:

```
rosterInput = input("New member or members: ")
while rosterInput != "0":
    roster.append(rosterInput)
    rosterInput = input("New member or members: ")
mainMenu()
```

To do it recursively, which is maybe closer to your original formulation:

```
roster = []
def add():
    # adding team members...
    rosterInput = input("New member or members: ")
    if rosterInput != "0":
        roster.append(rosterInput)
        add()
    else:
        mainMenu()
```

Initialize roster with the empty list outside the function to not overwrite it each time. You don't need the `global` statement here, since you're not reassigning roster, just mutating with `append`.

Comment: that solved the problem of it looping but when I enter 0 it exits the program instead of going to the mainMenu function

Comment: and if I put a name in first then a 0 it goes back to being stuck in the loop

Comment: now im facing the problem of 0 and only 0 being the list. So I entered multiple names then entered 0 to go back to the main menu and print the roster and it prints back [0]

Comment: Uh, yeah, sorry, I had thought of add as a stand-in for append and didn't realize it was the function that you defined there. I'll correct the answer.